Validations in spring boot are not worked when sending a list of object to request body
I'm sending a List of Object to request body like this :
@PatchMapping("/branches")
    public MicApiResponse<Void> updateForManyBranches(
            @RequestBody List<@Valid RepresentativeForManyBranchesRequest> req) throws MicClientException {
        service.updateForManyBranches(req);
        return MicApiResponse.succeed();
    }

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RepresentativeForManyBranchesRequest {
    @Valid
    private RepresentativeUserForManyBranchesRequest representativeUsers;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RepresentativeUserForManyBranchesRequest {
    private String id;
    @Required
    private String userId;
    @Required
    @Length(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String name;
    @Required
    @Length(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String position;}

These annotations @Required and @Length are worked when i send only one oject to request body, but when i send a list of object, they didn't work. What should I do to fix this problem ? Thanks a lot

try @NotNull or @NotBlank instead of @Required, the size of the list is not being considered here just checking the object may have values

@SanuKhan it still did not work, these annotations only worked when i send an object, not a list of object

I think you should write it like this
@Valid List<RepresentativeForManyBranchesRequest>

And you should also use @NotNull, @NotBlank or @NotEmpty rather than @Required.
@NotBlank
private String userId;

Or you can put your list in a wrapper object.

I tried, but it still did not work

@NghiHoàngĐức What version of Java and Spring Boot are you using?

i'm using java 11

@NghiHoàngĐức You should use @NotNull rather than @Required.

@NotNull is still not correct, it only worked when i sent an Object, not a list of object to Body

@NghiHoàngĐức I think it doesn't matter if it's one object or many objects if you validate the fields of the object.

@NghiHoàngĐức I checked in Spring Boot 3.3.4 on Java 17. @NotBlank, @NotNull and @NotEmpty work fine. You might want to wrap your list in a wrapper object.

Check the package (import statement) of the annotations. You should use Spring validation package
jakarta.validation.constraints

and not Hibernate one
org.hibernate.validator.constraints

For the up-to-date version use Spring Boot 3.3+ and Java 17+ Older versions didn't support validation of lists and needed custom validators.
